# Scrapy tutorial only crawling one page - tried everything in the current SO answer pages

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm having a problem with the Scrapy tutorial. No matter what solutions I enter from others' questions about Scrapy only crawling one page that I've found on the web (including all of them on SO), it only crawls one page. I'm experienced enough with Python that I'm almost completely sure it's not an indentation problem. Here is my current code, somewhat modified from the tutorial to reflect others' solutions that I've found. Note that I've also tried parse_item, and that didn't work either.

Basically, for my spider I am going to need to start with an .html page so I did so for my own tutorial purposes. Is this the problem - does it need to be a directory only?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

class DmozSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["mollydesjardin.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.mollydesjardin.com/"
    ]

    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_item')]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a common trap for `CrawlSpider`: you should not override the built-in `parse()` method (where all `CrawlSpider` magic happens), unless you know what you're doing.

[The warning is in the docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules) but many users miss it.

Rename your `parse()` method to `parse_item()` (as you declare in your rules).

Depending on what you need, you may want to add a `follow=True` to your rule, so that links found in grabbed pages (after the start URL) are also crawled.